# How to align two inputs horizontally

Tags: html, css, alignment, vertical-alignment, text-alignment

I am currently a very beginner in css and html. I am trying to make a login page, but i just can't align my two inputs. I want to have the labels "Username :" and "Password :" on the left of my text inputs, and that shift the inputs.

I have something that looks like this:

[image: shift between two inputs]

I want my two inputs to be aligned and not shifted like you can see on the image.

I tried to align my inputs with text-align, align-items, flex, or grid on CSS, but nothing did it. I managed to get them aligned if i put a "display: block;" in my CSS code, but it places the label on top of the input instead of on its left, which is what i want.
I guess i just don't understand how it works, and i hope someone can help me on deepening my understand of alignment on CSS.

```css
div.Loging {
  background: url("https://via.placeholder.com/800") no-repeat center center;
  background-size: cover;
  height: 800px;
  text-align: center;
}

div.Username-Password input {
  padding: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
```

```html
<link href='./index-style.css' rel='stylesheet'>

<head>
  <title>Site Guillaume Test</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="Loging">
    <h2>Login :</h2>
    <div class="Username-Password">
      <form>
        <label for="pseudo">Username :</label>
        <input type="text" name="pseudo" id="pseudo" placeholder="Enter Username" required>
        <br>
        <label for="password">Password :</label>
        <input type="password" name="password" id="password" placeholder="Enter Password" required>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: I've linked a few duplicates above. They'll help resolve the problem I mentioned on the solution below, which isn't ideal. Note that colon characters go against the text they apply to, such as `Log in: `. Don't put spaces before them. That's incorrect from a language style perspective and it also results in weird wrapping in some cases. (I'd actually eliminate all three of your colons; they're not needed.) Also note that "Login" is a noun. Your form caption should really be "Log in" (the verb form). Happy coding.

Comment: Thank you very much ! I will look into the solution you linked, happy coding !

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Using the code you provided - changing as little as possible - is this what you were looking for?

[StackBlitz for reference and editing](https://stackblitz.com/edit/web-platform-yz6ezq?file=index.html)

```css
div.Loging {
  background: url("./images/index-background.jpg") no-repeat center center;
  background-size: cover;
  height: 800px;
  text-align: center;
}

.Username-Password input {
  padding: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.Username-Password {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.input-group {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: baseline;
}

form {
  width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="Loging">
    <h2>Login :</h2>
    
    <div class="Username-Password">
      <form>
        <div class="input-group">
          <label for="pseudo">Username :</label>
          <input type="text" name="pseudo" id="pseudo" placeholder="Enter Username" required>
        </div>
        
        <div class="input-group">
          <label for="password">Password :</label>
          <input type="password" name="password" id="password" placeholder="Enter Password" required>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: This fails if the labels are of differing lengths. It's not a good strategy to individually pad elements. It's fragile.